# query to find count of records on daily basis for given time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to count no of records in a table daily between 9 AM to 6 PM on a given date range.

Sample output should look like:

```
Date          Count of users
01-11-2018    100
02-11-2018    88
03-11-2018    107
04-11-2018    113
```

Comment: Do you store time in date column?

Comment: From your sample data, how would anyone know what time values are for a record

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DATE(date), count(*) 
FROM table 
WHERE TIME(date) BETWEEN TIME('9:00:00') AND TIME('18:00:00') 
GROUP BY DATE(date)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `date`, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   table_name tn 
WHERE  tn.date >= Timestampadd(hour, 9, Curdate()) 
       AND tn.date <= Timestampadd(hour, 18, Curdate()) 
GROUP  BY `date`
```